# Scala - Undo a flatmap after transformation

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, scala-collections

How can I merge a `Seq` of `Maps` to a single `Map` i.e.

```
Seq[Map[String, String]] => Map[String, String]
```

For example:

```
val someSeq = rdd.map(_._2).flatMap(...)  //some transformation to produce the sequence of maps
```

where `someSeq` is `Seq(student1, student2)` and `student1` and `student2` are `Maps` :

```
var student1 = Map(a -> "1", b -> "1")
var student2 = Map(c -> "1", d -> "1")
```

I need a result like this:

```
val apps = Map(a -> "1", b -> "1", c -> "1", d -> "1")
```

Any idea ?

Comment: I'm not sure when Spark is taken into account in your question, but usually you would do `val apps = someSeq.flatten.toMap` in Scala.

Comment: And what `Seq` is doing here?  `RDD` is not a `Seq`...

Comment: @jwvh: good point but both Maps are unique but am curious to know how to handle that also. Any suggestion ?

Comment: @zero323: it's just an intermediate transformation I need to perfom on my RDD e.g. `stream.transform{...flatmap(...)}.foreachRDD(...)`

Comment: But `transform` takes a function `RDD[T] => RDD[U]`, doesn't it? So where the output map fits in? Or if you prefer what are the actual types of `rdd` and `someSeq`?

Answer (score 3):

Unrelated to Spark, but one approach would be to fold over the sequence as follows:

```
val student1 = Map("a" -> "1", "b" -> "1")
val student2 = Map("c" -> "1", "d" -> "1")

val students = Seq(student1, student2)

students.foldLeft(Map[String, String]())(_ ++ _)
```

Returns

```
Map(a -> 1, b -> 1, c -> 1, d -> 1)
```

In regards to "undoing" a flatMap, I don't believe this is really possible.  In order to achieve that, consider the notion of undoing a "flatten".

For example:

```
val x = Seq(1, 2)
val y = Seq(3, 4)
val combined = Seq(x, y)
val flattened = combined.flatten

val b = Seq(1, 2, 3)
val c = Seq(4)
val combined2 = Seq(b, c)
val flattened2 = combined2.flatten

flattened == flattened2
```

Returns true.

So basically, in this instance, you can go from unflattened to flattened, but not vice versa, because vice versa would yield multiple answers.